# How to add a custom paragraph style in my SharePoint 2013 blog?

Tags: asp.net, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a Share Point 2013 web site and a blog in it. Since my posts will include a lot of special text content, I need to add more styles that I will use on all posts. Typically all styles appear in the top ribbon bar when creating a  new post.

[image: Style selection]

How to add the new style in Share Point Designer 2013?
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are custom styles for the SharePoint RichText editor. The nice thing is that all you have to do is add some custom CSS and SharePoint will magically render new text styles. you can also do this with SharePoint Designer if you have a custom master page or if you just specify the alternate CSS somewhere.

The "magic" CSS is something like the following:

```
.ms-rteStyle-MySpecialStyle {
    -ms-name: "My special style";
    font-style: bold;
    color: red;
}
h2.ms-rteElement-SpecialHeading{
    -ms-name: "Special Heading";
    font-style: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

The difference between the two is the `rteElement` vs. `rteStyles`, but the difference becomes clear once you look at your screenshot: Page Elements and Text Styles. The difference is that you style particular *elements* with one, e.g. H1, H2, SPAN, and you style text passages with the other - SharePoint actually adds a `span` tag around the text and assigns it your style.

Enough of the words, a couple of complete blog articles to help you get started:

- [How to add custom styles to the ribbon in SharePoint 2013](http://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx)
- [Add new stlyes to Rich Text Editor ribbon in SP2013 Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59224/add-new-stlyes-to-rich-text-editor-ribbon-in-sp2013-online)
- [Do you know how to custom styles for RichHtmlEditor in SharePoint 2013?](http://rules.ssw.com.au/SoftwareDevelopment/RulesToBetterSharePoint/Pages/CustomStylesForRichHtmlEditor.aspx)

Comment: Very nice answer... but I cannot find layout pages in my site... how can I add one? I had to put it in the master page....

Comment: what do you mean by layout pages? as i mentioned in the answer the madter page is the right way to go or put it into the CustomCSS of your web

Comment: Yes sorry it is in the first link in the list of three  links you provided... I went for the master page and it is ok, but I wnated to use a layoutpage as suggested by the first link... but can't create a layout page, maybe I should ask this into another question...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for custom heading and text

```
h2.ms-rteStyle-customHeading
{-ms-name:"custom heading";
 color:gray;  }

.ms-rteElement-customTest 
-ms-name:"customize text";
{color:black; }
```